# admob показывает только тестовую рекламу

Tags: android, admob

```
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-39402xxxx9942544/xxxx173712");

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    Toast.makeText(appState, " посмотрел рекламу и стал молодцом", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        requestNewInterstitial();
}
      private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = null;
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

                    //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .build();
            Toast.makeText(appState, "не Релиз", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .build();
            Toast.makeText(appState, "Релиз", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

показываю так

```
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                                mInterstitialAd.show();
                            }
```

Но всегда выводится тестовый баннер

Comment: проблема скорее всего не в коде, проверьте настройки рекламы в личном кабинете в admob. Подождите часов 6.

Comment: Жду уже более 12 часов. А что смотреть? На первый взгляд все настроено. В гугл залил релиз версию, скачал и установил, запускаю, а там выходит тестовая реклама.. Проверял на нескольких телефонах с разными учетками гугла, все равно выходит тестовая реклама